# How to send message from widget to iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, widget

I'm implementing a widget extension with 3 buttons. These buttons are meant to trigger a method in my iOS app. Is this possible? I know you can share data with UserDefaults but I want to trigger a function right from the widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it (and the way Apple [suggests](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)) is to create an embedded framework with all the common code and methods you need your main app and your widget to share and import that framework to both targets.